# How to clear the background tasks queue manually when user no longer wants this functionality?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The user schedules a background task (i.e. turns on notifications in the app) by pressing a button that does this:

```
WKApplication.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5), userInfo: nil) { (error: Error?) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error occured while scheduling background refresh: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("scheduled")
    }
}
```

And this task is handled as such:

```
class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, WKApplicationDelegate {
    func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
        for task in backgroundTasks {
            // schedule a new task for tomorrow ✅

            // refresh app data - in progress

            // immediately trigger a local notification with fresh data ✅
            
            task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, should a user turn notifications off, this action must clear all pending notification requests ✅, but this is moot as the scheduled background task will still run and the loop and notifications will resume next day (or, at the very least, the background task will continue to run regardless of a notification firing or not).  I can't find documentation on how to unschedule/remove already scheduled background task(s), how can this be done actively by the user (by clicking a button)?

Comment: Probably you should store their notification preference in user defaults. Then, when your background task runs you consult that to check if you should actually deliver a notification.  You don't need to check what is in the queue since you can only have one task scheduled. Scheduling another task cancels any existing scheduled task.

Comment: was already saving notification preference with @appstorage and completely forgot that it was accessible through userdefaults in the appdelegate...  with there only being one task at a time (finally found that in the docs too), solution is easy: guard the notification function with an if, and schedule the background task when the app becomes inactive. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no background task "queue" as such; you can only have one background task scheduled at a time.  Scheduling a new task cancels any previously scheduled task (so technically it is a queue with a maximum depth if 1 )

When your background task starts, check the user's preferences to see if they still want notifications.  If they do, post the notification and schedule another task.  If not, you're done.

Whenever your watch app leaves the foreground you can check if notifications are enabled and schedule a background task.

If there was no previously scheduled task, well now there is. If there was a previously scheduled task, then you have just replaced it; no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you let the old task fire and then ignore it, it will count against your background task budget.

Another approach is to schedule a new task in the very distant future. The new task will replace the previously scheduled task.  This approach has two advantages: 1) no need to remember whether the user has canceled the task and, more importantly, 2) the task won't count against the background budget.