# Handle scheduled background task whilst app is in foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The below functionality (at a user's button press, schedule a background task which, when run, schedules itself again for a future time, and performs some other actions, indefinitely, or until user cancels feature) works perfectly if the app is in the background.

However, if the app is in the foreground, the handler doesn't execute.  Apple's docs seem to imply that they should unless I specify to ignore the tasks somehow (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/background_execution/using_background_tasks "If watchOS calls your handle(_:) method while your app is in the foreground, you can ignore the tasks, call setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(_:), and return.")

What am I missing/incorrectly implementing?  The app should run the background task whether the app is in the foreground or background as it's essential for ensuring the next notification is scheduled.

An alternative solution I can think of is having the app delegate schedule the background task if there is no background task already scheduled (and the app state is such that the user expects there to be).  However, this seems to be getting messy and I'm not sure how to even access to count the background tasks queue?

```
WKApplication.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5), userInfo: nil) { (error: Error?) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error occured while scheduling background refresh: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("scheduled")
    }
}
```

```
class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, WKApplicationDelegate {
    func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
        for task in backgroundTasks {
            // schedule a new task for tomorrow ✅

            // refresh app data - in progress

            // immediately trigger a local notification with fresh data ✅
            
            task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The system *may* call `handle` if your app is in the foreground, but then again it *may not*.  The assumption is that when your app is in the foreground that it can use other techniques, such as a `Timer` to perform periodic tasks.

Comment: Also, see Apple's note "When designing your app, don’t expect the system to trigger every background task. Design a fallback mechanism so that your app behaves correctly even when throttling occurs. For example, even if your app never receives any background tasks, it can still update its state whenever the user launches it in the foreground." You cannot rely on background tasks as you only method of update.

Comment: timer doesn’t seem quite appropriate in this instance as i’m already handling the data refresh when in the foreground, and a user would probably rather get no notification than get one with old info (hence why i’m tying the notification to the task of refreshing data). a solution could be to check on close of app if a background task is scheduled if notifications are wanted by the user. if so, we know functionality is correct. if no, we know it’s failed and can schedule it now. so: how can i check what is in the background tasks queue?

Comment: i think the answer to that might strongly relate to my other question about clearing the queue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75542732/19427065

Comment: I commented on that question,  it in summary, check the users notification setting when the background task fires and you can only ever have one task scheduled, so just schedule one if you need it. There is no "queue".